# A search query that has any one, or all, of the following

Tags: mysql

I'm currently writing a query and can't seem to get it right, so I'm writing to get some advice.

I have a `props` table `[userId, name]` (where `name` is a property).

| userId | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | A |

Suppose have data like this

To search for name, we received data of ["A","B"].

1. To find the contents of any of them, I could have issued a query like the one below to find userId 1,2,3,4.

```sql
select userId from props where name in ("A","B") group by userId;
```

I'm not sure how to process the query to find something that has both.

If I want to find ["A","B"] as above, the search result should be two userId 1,3.

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: What about `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I want to find ["A","B"] as above, the search result should be two
> userId 1,3.

You can do it [as here in SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05bb5e/1)

```
SELECT userId
FROM props
WHERE name IN ("A", "B")
GROUP BY userId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) = 2;
```

This will give you the expected result :

```
userId
1
3
```